# Connect Wifi Thermostat to Goodman GMP050-3?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I'm trying to connect up a wifi thermostat to Goodman furnace, specifically the GMP050-3.

I've done some reading on this but I'm still not quite sure how to go about it. Specifically, I'm not sure how (or if) I can find a substitute for the C wire on my wifi thermostat. Thanks.

Schematic:
[image]

[image]

And here are photos of the actual furnace wiring:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a photo of where the existing thermostat cable connects to the furnace wiring?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not the first person with this furnace.
If you have air conditioning then...
http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r28226387-goodman-GMP050-3-Gas-Furnace-where-to-find-24vac
If not then do you have a voltmeter?
You are looking for constant 24 volts a.c..
Might be that BL wire that connects to the C1 terminal. Check between there and the R terminal.

Answer (score 0):

One of the terminals of the transformer has 3 blue wires attached.  Use that terminal as the "C" terminal.

Comment: It may not be clear to the OP *how* one would do that....

Comment: Could you expand on that ?  Use [edit] to add details.