# Please help me find the right spot to tap into for C wire at the furnace

Tags: wiring, thermostat, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I am trying to upgrade our thermostat to a Wifi unit that needs a C-wire.  Found the unused C wire at the thermostat end and connected it.  AC wouldn't power on, went to furnace end and found it wasn't connected there either.  I am not sure which of the nuts to tap into to power the C-wire and would appreciate any help.  It is a Goodman unit, I found some previous posts with the same unit but the wiring on those didn't seem to match mine.

EDIT #1: Added more photos. Looked all over panels (including the inside cover) and could not find a wiring diagram.  I can confirm it is a Goodman GMP050-3.

Thanks all, especially Dr. Sparks.

[image: a bunch of wires, nutted together]

[image: same bunch of wires, different angle]

[image: distant shot of the wires connected to controller board]

Comment: Showing a bunch of wires connected together doesn't help much - wiring colors are _reasonably_ standardized, but that doesn't guarantee they were used on your installation. Please take pics of the wiring at the thermostat end and the actual wiring terminal block of the furnace - if there is any labeling at the wiring block, be sure it's in focus and readable. Additionally a pic of the wiring diagram label on the furnace would be very helpful. [Edit] these pics into your post.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is an install I'm doing at my parents house, I'll get back there this afternoon and get some more pics.  Unfortunately, I didn't see a wiring diagram anywhere on or near the furnace but I'll check again.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate question. The model number on the nameplate looks like a GMP050-3, wiring diagram can be found here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/145411/connect-wifi-thermostat-to-goodman-gmp050-3

Comment: It might be on the inside of the cover panel. I just had my HVAC replaced. The company wired it for a C wire, but I've got an old-school analog, 2-stage stat. When I turned on the heat for the first time, it blew a fuse. I reported the error code to my HVAC guy, but never even thought to look at the inside of the panel where there was a _huge_ sticker explaining _all_ the error codes...

Comment: Good find, @PlatinumGoose. I'm not sure this deserves a VtC (which you don't seem to have done) because there are no "good" answers there. Well, there is an answer that appears to be correct, but it's a bit brief, has no up votes, nor is it accepted. Might be better to get the wiring diagram (and model number) included here, then close that as a dupe of this. ;)

Comment: From that other not-quite-answered question and the photos there, the unit's  transformer has one red and three blue wires connected to it.   It would be helpful if you provide photos of the connection point or points of those three blue wires to the transformer, and of the other end of each of those blue wires, wherever each is connected to something.   Hopefully one of those places (two ends of three blue wires) will provide a convenient connection point for your C wire.

Comment: There is a thicker white, green, and red wire in your photo.  You need to find out where those wires go.  Also, there will be a 24v transformer that connects to the control board of the air handler.  They typically have a red and black wire, but the colors can vary and aren't ultimately important.  You need to find out where those two wires connect as well.  Either they both connect to the control board, or one does and the other connects to the metal chassis of the air handler.  Look around.

Comment: [Installation manual](https://www.questargas.com/ForEmployees/qgcOperationsTraining/Furnaces/Goodman_GMP_GMPE.pdf) if that helps anyone

Comment: You posted 4 copies of the same photo. It would be helpful if you could replace at least one with a close up that shows the labeling on the different connection blocks.

Comment: I'm glad you got this resolved! If you'll spend a moment taking the [tour], you'll see that editing your question to provide the answer isn't the way we do things around here. Please copy/paste your "edit" into the "Answer" box down below, then, as soon as the system allows you to, you can click the check mark to tell others this has been successfully resolved. Self answers like that are not only allowed, they're _encouraged_!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

Tried connecting the C-wire (thin baby blue wire off the thermostat bundle) at the furnace end to a few different connections, but could not get the thermostat to turn on.

Of note, I was not putting the metal cover back on and finally realized the cover has to be on to compress a black switch in order for the unit to turn on. Success!

I'll include a picture with a blue arrow pointing to the right tap in point (picture was taken prior to adding C-wire).  The Honeywell T5 turned on, and after what felt like an eternity of flashing "Cool On" the AC finally cycled on.

[image: arrow pointing to appropriate wire bundle]

Comment: Thanks!! +1 from me. I included your pic from the original "solved edit", since you reference it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you'll need a voltmeter for this. Set your voltmeter to AC volts. Look on the right side of the photo. That's your control transformer. One terminal of that transformer is going to the control board to feed the R terminal. The C terminal is the opposing terminal on the transformer. Check each terminal on the transformer against the R terminal on the right. The one that measures approximately 24 VAC is your C terminal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dr. Sparks, I tried the connection you circled but it didn't work. I also tried the white (the only other wire coming off the budle with that red one) which is connected to the thick bluish/gray wire (which is connected to a screw on the board and I assume is a ground wire) but without success.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please try this.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Voltmeter on hand. Anything else I could try?

Comment: Yes, just use trial and error. Try connecting your C wire to one of the secondary terminals on your transformer. See if it comes on. If it doesn't, try the other. You'll either have 0v or 24v so you can't hurt the thermostat trying this.